# Need help validating radio buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I need help validating radio buttons with JavaScript. Here's the section of HTML:

```html
<span class="formbold">Will you be attending the ceremony and reception?</span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesboth" /> Yes, both!<br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesc" /> Yes, but only the ceremony! <br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesr" /> Yes, but only the reception!<br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="no" /> No, you guys are lame!
```

And here's the simplest validation code I have:

```javascript
function validateForm()
    var y=document.forms["rsvpform"]["receptionattend"].checked;
 if (y==null || y=="")
    {
    alert("Please indicate whether or not you will attend.");
    return false;
    }
}
```

My issue mostly seems to be that, no matter how I code the validation, it returns an error message even when I have a radio button selected.

Comment: `y` is always going to have a value, either `true` or `false`, you should check for `false` :: `if (!y) {}`

Comment: Now it's not even giving me my error message. My issue before was I got the message even when I chose an option. :S

Comment: Oops! My apologies, I changed something else without realising. Still having the error message at all times issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue you have is that in general, you should force a default in your radio buttons, make one of the buttons be already "checked" and you will never have a null value passed to your form checker. Most people expect their radio buttons to have a default already checked and this is standard practice in web development.

However, should you need to check for null or undefined, you should use **typeof** and strict comparison with ===

```
 (typeof y === "undefined" || y === null);
```

After reading your comment - I noticed one other thing. Are you trying get get the value directly from Javascript by reading the DOM with like an onclick function? You won't be able to do this because you aren't ever actually getting your checked value with this line.

```
var y=document.forms["rsvpform"]["receptionattend"].checked;
```

Instead, try something like this.

```
var y = document.getElementsByName('receptionattend');
var y_value;
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    if(y[i].checked){
       y_value = y[i].value;
   }
}
```

y_value should now return the result of the checked radio button.  If nothing was checked y_value will be null.

Comment: I've tried using this, but I'm still getting a error message even when I have an option selected.

Comment: On a side note, I'll disagree with the blanket statement that you should check a radio button by default. There are times when you want the user to have to actualy think about what they are doing. Often a user will leave a radio button in the default state out of lazyness/ignorance/apathy. For example in a survey, you want the user to explicitly choose an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you Ashley!  @Jon P - Radio button group represents a 1 of many selection like a single-select list or dropdown. Its best to always have exactly one radio button selected. Refer to [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio

If you need to make sure a user makes a choice, you could let the pre-selected choice be 'Not specified' analogous to an empty or a '--Select one--' first element in a drop-down.

Not having a pre-selected choice is a bit weird, since you then have a state to which the user cannot go back. Once he has made a choice, he can't undo it.

Comment: I agree that *most* times you should set a default, but I disagree that you should *always* set a default. I'll set a default 90-95% of the time. I wouldn't for example present a radiobutton that wasn't a valid selection, your "Not Specified" for example, then via validation inform the user that it is not a valid selection. To me thats worse than not pre-selecting an option. I know I'm arging against the spec here and leave it at that as this isn't the forum for an extended debate.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
var y=document.forms["rsvpform"]["receptionattend"].checked;
```

returns either `true` or `false` based on checked attribute of your element, so you should be doing:

```
if ( !y ) { //if not checked i.e false
    alert("Please indicate whether or not you will attend.");
    return false;
}
```

do like:

```
function validateForm() {
    var is_checked = false;
    var eles = document.forms["rsvpform"]["receptionattend"];
    for(var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++ ) {
        if( eles[i].checked ) {
            is_checked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!is_checked)
    {
        alert("Please indicate whether or not you will attend.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("valid");
     }
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srVqC/)

Comment: Ok, I'm still having an issue. It returns an error message even when I've selected an option.

Comment: @AshleyMarieRoberts check the added answer with demo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to suggest using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) just for this. But should you end up using jquery, it makes this kind of validation very easy.

**HTML** Note the use of Labels, this is just a good practice, it means your uses can click on the text and a whole raft of other accesibililty bonuses.

```
<span class="formbold">Will you be attending the ceremony and reception?</span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesboth" id="rcBoth" /><label for="rcBoth">Yes, both!</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesc" id="rcCOnly" /><label for="rcCOnly"> Yes, but only the ceremony! </label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="yesr" id="rcROnly" /><label for="rcROnly">Yes, but only the reception!</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="receptionattend" value="no" id="rcNo" /><label for="rcNo"> No, you guys are lame!</label><br />
<input type="button" value="Validate Me" id="btnValidate"/>
```

**Javascript/Jquery** Wire this up in the jquery $(document).ready event.

```
$("#btnValidate").click(function(){
    //The following selector is not very efficient, classes 
    //or a bounding element (eg div or fieldset) would be better
    if($("input[name='receptionattend']:checked").length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please tell us if you're attending or not!");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpMvp/

To break down the script

- `$("#btnValidate").click(function(){});` adds an `onlclick` event handler to the button with ID `btnValidate`
- `$("input[name='receptionattend']:checked").length` returns how many input elements with a name of `receptionattend` are checked
- the rest should be fairy self explanatory